# Can 适合 ("to suit") be used as an intransitive verb?

Tags: usage, verbs

There's [Difference between 合适 and 适合](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/difference-between-%e5%90%88%e9%80%82-and-%e9%80%82%e5%90%88), which explains how [合适](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%90%88%E9%80%82) is an adjective:

> 不**合适**的性行为有什么害处 ([source](http://tag.120ask.com/jingyan/2zwvu5sk3lwmu571x3wm9ysksk.html))
> Un**suit**able sexual behavior has what harm
>
> 找个**合适**的结婚对象，真的好难 ([source](http://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1653084243519957183&wfr=spider&for=pc))
> searching [for] a **suit**able marriage partner [is] really difficult

whereas [适合](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E9%80%82%E5%90%88) is an verb:

> 那种牧草最**适合**牛吃 ([source](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1370388066616391619.html))
> That kind of pasture most **suit**s cows to eat
>
> 我**适合**什么职业? ([source](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/6317856445))
> I **suit** what occupation?

However, YouDao lists [适合](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E9%80%82%E5%90%88) as both a transitive and *intransitive* verb (i.e., no object):

> vi. fit

I'm not sure this is correct as I don't recall ever seeing it as an intransitive verb, so want to check.

**Question**: Can 适合 be used as an intransitive verb?

If so, please give some illustrative examples.

Comment: Maybe, 我们两个不适合 can be one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mind it. Youdao is an online dictionary aiming at helping Chinese learn English. When it lists 'v.i. fit' as a translation for 适合, it means that 'fit' is an intransitive verb (though not always the case).

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Can 适合 be used as an intransitive verb

Intransitive verbs do not take object.  You cannot add an object to 他生病了 and make it 他生病了你, you cannot add an object to 他自殺了 and make it 他自殺了你

"适合" in "老師的工作他很适合" doesn't followed by an object, but it doesn't mean there's no object. The object is "老師的工作" (placing the object before the verb to emphasize it is a common practice)

If you remove "老師的工作"(teacher job) and write 他很适合 (he fit), then it would not be a complete sentence anymore

You can use "他很适合" as an answer to  the question "他适合老師的工作嗎?" because the object is implied in the question. But I wouldn't call 适合 an intransitive verb in this case.

I can't think of any case that 'fit' doesn't need an object. there have to be something to be fitted in